# f(x) vs f×x: Functions vs Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, notation

Might be a stupid question, but I was thinking about this today and wanted to clear something up. I always thought of f(x) as having different algebraic properties than f×x, and it came as a surprise to me when I noticed that you can modify the equation algebraically, treating $f(x)$ as $f×x$, without *necessarily* butchering the original function.

Most rudimentarily:

$f(x) = x$

$\frac {f(x)}x = \frac xx$

$f(1) = 1$

I was able to get the answer by simply dividing x out of the function $f(x)$ as if it were being multiplied by another variable.

Another example:

$f(x) = x+2$

$f(x) × \frac2x=\frac{2x}x+\frac4x$

$f(2) = 2+\frac4x$

This one's a little different, as you'd need to plug the value within f that has replaced x into the equation, but

$f(x) = 2+\frac4x$ (the equation we ended up with)

$2+\frac4{(2)} = 4 = f(2)$

$f(x) = x+2$

$(2)+2=4 = f(2)$

Yes, I realize that if I were to plug anything into x that was not the constant in the parentheses, the new derived function would not work. Regardless, I thought it was interesting that function notation and algebraic notation have such a distinctive intersection (for lack of better phrasing). The only difference between $f(x)$ and $f×x$ is that the equation on the opposite end of $f(x)$ remains consistent regardless of what number you plug in in place of x, whereas the equation accompanying $f×x$ changes based on what you want to substitute for x. Is this just another mathematical coincidence, of sorts?

Apologies if this is fallaciously thought out, or poorly worded. I don't know math in and out and this thought is rather fresh.

Comment: If $*$ is the standard multiplication, then try with a non linear function. Otherwise define it. Usually $*$ is used to denote the convolution operation

Comment: I guess in some cases, $f(x)$ acts similarly to an operation, telling you what to do with $x$. For example, $f(x, n)$ could be the notation to describe an operation which tells you to $x^n$.

Comment: Apologies, Marco. I'll change that now.

Comment: And yeah, Lucien. I suppose it's just a question of how the function notation translates into algebraic notation. I would imagine the creation of a lot of new notations was just abbreviated versions of old notation.

Comment: Karl, either I accidentally deleted your comment or you did. Either way, here's my reply.

$f$ and $f(1)$ are the same, no? Diving x out of $f(x)$ would get you $f(1)$. Similarly, multiplying 
$f(x)$ with $\frac2x$ would get you $f(2)$

Comment: I suppose it's just another coincidence, like how 2×2 = $2^2$. Just an overcomplicated matter of where the two notations intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in functions $f$ with the property that for all numbers $x$ and $y$, we have $f(y)=f(x)\frac yx$. This is equivalent to $\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{f(y)}y$, i.e. $\frac{f(x)}x$ is a constant $c$ that doesn't depend on $x$. So the only functions with this property are of the form $f(x)=cx$. This makes sense in hindsight, since you're trying to treat the "$f$" as a multiplied constant.

In your second example, you "cheated" by plugging 2 in again for the remaining occurrence of $x$. Functions for which this works satisfy $f(y)=f(x)\frac yx[x\to y]$, where the $[x\to y]$ indicates that we replace occurrences of $x$ with $y$. But this clearly true for all functions because $f(x)\frac yx[x\to y]=f(y)\frac yy=f(y)$. In other words, you're multiplying $f(x)$ by $\frac yx$ and then plugging in $y$ for $x$ so that the $f(x)$ becomes $f(y)$ and the $\frac yx$ becomes $1$.